# Difficulty in displaying the relationship on the ER-Diagram

Tags: databases, data-science

An assignment from my university told me to make a chart that would display an airline company database. but there was a difficulty with the task:

**Certain flights wait for other flights if possible. Such flights form pairs of  connecting flights.**

As I assume, a recursive relationship with an attribute is being used here. Something like that:

**Flight ---- awaits ---- Flight**

But the problem is that I couldn't find anywhere to support this hypothesis. I was misled by the statement that such flights form connection flights. It is not clear to me, should I implement this as an attribute at the received relation, or should it be an associative entity? If it is an associative entity, then how should it be related to the Flight entity

Comment: Sorry, but this site is for questions about Academia and how to navigate it, so this is off topic here. Frankly, I think you just need to ask your professor since nobody else can know what exactly they expect of you.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did ER (but learned it from a master). I thought ER only captured static relationships and you are asking about dynamics. What is the static relationship between the entities?